# how to make ordered multiple choosing recyclerview kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, android-recyclerview, multiple-choice

i am a begginer in adroid development. i want to make an app in which a person chooses points in the order he wants and after that he starts to drive from one point to another. so i want to make an ordered multiple choosing of list of items, but i cant find anything. can I realize such recyclerview using koltin, but instead of check marks there would be number in which the item was selected, and after that adding all the selected items into array in that order?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgHPN.jpg)

Comment: it's not necessary to use the recyclerview

Comment: RecyclerView is appropriate for this. The data class that represents the items of the list can have an integer property to represent selection order, with -1 representing that it has not been selected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.